# Solana idiomatic pattern for a list

Tags: data-modelling, architecture

I wanted to understand the solana community idioms around modeling unique data(Hashset) or Openzepplin version of a Set on solidity and storing them on chain, the problems I feel are 2

1. List/Hashset has to be finite(max data account size limitation) the
   max size it can occupy is 10 mb(is it a better solution to start small and use realloc to conserve account costs ?)
2. In scenarios where a list exceeds its max size is there a way to
   start another list and keep going as soon as the previous one
   exceeds its max size.

Need suggestions or refrences to already existing oss programs that deal with this and achieve a solution on how to model lists , say a list of unique items what is the solana idiom around modelling this datatype for e.g for a hashmap the solana equivalent is a pda, if so what is the solana equivalent for a list or a unique list ?